# docker-machine on Linux subsystem for Windows can't connect to running host

Tags: ubuntu, docker, hyper-v, docker-machine, bash-on-windows

I'm running Docker for Windows 17.06.2-ce on Windows 10 1703 build 16278.1000.

I have created a cluster with two Hyper-V hosts similair to https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#understanding-swarm-clusters.

When I run `docker-machine ls` from a Windows command prompt I get the following output:

[image: docker-machine ls from command prompt]

I can also use `docker-machine ssh myvm1` to ssh into the host.

I've setup Ubuntu Linux Subsystem for Windows. I've added the PATH variables for Docker to `.bashrc` and added aliases for `docker.exe` and `docker-machine.exe`. However, when using docker from the Ubuntu bash, the regular docker commands work OK but `docker-machine ls` gives me the following:

[image: docker-machine ls from command prompt]

Running `docker-machine ssh myvm1` from Ubuntu gives the following error:

```
Error: Cannot run SSH command: Host "myvm1" is not running
```

Is it possible to use docker-machine from the Linux subsystem to access Hyper-v hosts running on the local machine? What can I do to fix the error I get?

Comment: I believe it may be because of hyperv driver. Can you add the same machines using the generic drivers also and see if those work? https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/#options

Answer (score 3):

I had the same symptoms when running "docker-machine ls" and "docker-machine ssh myvm1" from command prompt **without** Administrator privileges.

Powershell under Administrator worked as expected.